# sessionStorage variable returning undefined in LWC component for a Flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, sessionstorage

I am unable to get sessionStorage work in my LWC component which is being used in a flow. My sample LWC component provided below is having a radio-button. In real, the purpose of the LWC is more complex as it is pulling the data through API, however, to focus on the issue, I have just put a sample code. Basically, I am trying to achieve the OOTB behavior of Flow Screen radio-button choice, which retains the selected option as you navigate next or previous across flow screens in the same flow runtime.

As in the screenshot below, I see that the sessionStorage variable is storing the value when I select one of the choices (say 'foo'), however when I click Next and come back to this screen again, for some reason, the variable is returning undefined. My expectation is the choice 'foo' should still be selected. Any help would be really appreciated.

**Screenshot**
[image]
**HTML**

```
<template>
    <lightning-radio-group name="choices" label="Choices" options={options} value={value} type="radio" onchange={handleChange}>
     </lightning-radio-group>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class SampleLWC extends LightningElement {
   options = [{
        label : 'foo',
        value: 'foo'
    },
    {
        label : 'bar',
        value: 'bar'
    }
    ];
    value = '';

    connectedCallback(){
        console.log('sessionVar: ' + window.sessionStorage.getItem['sessionVar']);
        if(window.sessionStorage.getItem['sessionVar']) {
            this.value = window.sessionStorage.getItem['sessionVar'];
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('sessionVar', event.detail.value);
        console.log('session storage stored: ' + window.sessionStorage.getItem['sessionVar']);
    }
}
```

**Meta**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: can you try using sessionStorage instead of window.sessionStorage? It might have to do with component vs window sessionStorage.

Comment: I tried using sessionStorage instead of window.sessionStorage but that did not work.

Comment: There was a typo in my code. I was able to get this fixed by replacing [] with () in all getItem() methods.